# Mejorar apariencia de tabla con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Tengo el siguiente código en `head` para darle mejor apariencia a mi tabla pero alguna razón no funciona, la tabla se queda como esta, qué puede ser?

```
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>
    Tabla PHP
</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" 
src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"> </script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready( function () 
    {
    $('#tabla1').DataTable();
    } );

</script>

</head>
<?php

    require("coneccion/conexion.php");


    print("Coneccion exitosa </br>");

$tablacontenido=''; $tabla = "CALL TraerTodos();"; $r= mysqli_query($l, $tabla); if ($r) { while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_object($r)) {

            $tablacontenido= $tablacontenido.'<tr>'.
            '<td>'. $reg->nombre.'</td>'
            .'<td>'. $reg->apellido.'</td>'
            .'<td>'. $reg->usuario.'</td>'
            .'<td>'. $reg->clave.'</td>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print "Error en la operacion de tabla </br>";
    }


?>

<table id="tabla1">
    <thead>

        <tr>
            <td>Nombre</td>
            <td>Apellido</td>
            <td>Nombre de Usuario</td>
            <td>Contraseña</td>
        </tr>

    </thead>



<?php

    echo "$tablacontenido";

?>
```

Comment: ¿Podés compartirnos el código HTML de la tabla? Más bien, tu documento HTML para validar que estés importando bien [la librería](https://datatables.net/).

Comment: ¿Qué dice la [consola del navegador](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Tools/Browser_Console)?

Answer (score 0):

Deberías fijarte si la llamada al jquery esta correcta. Esto lo puedes ver en la consola debug del browser ya que si no es correcta marca un error.

El jquery  lo estas buscando en el mismo folder donde esta el PHP.  Sin este js no podras ver la apariencia de la tabla ya que el jquery.dataTable depende del mismo.

Repliqué el código sin el PHP y llamé al jquery desde code.jquery.com para probar

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>
        Tabla PHP
    </title>
    <script
            src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-Ls0pXSlb7AYs7evhd+VLnWsZ/AqEHcXBeMZUycz/CcA="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function ()
        {
            $('#tabla1').DataTable();
        } );
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="tabla1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>Apellido</td>
        <td>Nombre de Usuario</td>
        <td>Contraseña</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Nombre Contenido 1</td>
        <td>Apellido contenido 1</td>
        <td>Nombre de Usuario contenido 1</td>
        <td>Contraseña contenido 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Nombre Contenido 1</td>
        <td>Apellido contenido 1</td>
        <td>Nombre de Usuario contenido 1</td>
        <td>Contraseña contenido 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Nombre Contenido 1</td>
        <td>Apellido contenido 1</td>
        <td>Nombre de Usuario contenido 1</td>
        <td>Contraseña contenido 1</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

El mismo funciona, con lo que creo que tu problema se encuentra en la llamada al [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Si funciono gracias